Novu sending push notifications using Firebase
I am working on a project using Novu to send notifications to my clients.
When I try to send push notifications using firebase, I get these errors even though the message is sent.
"Sending message failed due to \"Requested entity was not found.\""

"Sending message failed due to \"SenderId mismatch\""

What is the issue here?
